# ipad: losing focus when bring context menu for textarea (safari/chrome)

Tags: ios, ipad, google-chrome, safari

I'm having an issue with losing focus on my forum (ipad, ios7, safari/chrome).

1. Open http://share.ghostwolf.eu/ipad_test/
2. Navigate to a quick reply form at the bottom of the page.
3. Start typing text
4. Tap to bring context menu
5. Continue typing after menu appeared

Result: nothing happens, text is not type.

Expected: context menu should disappear and text should successfully typing.

How can I fix the issue? Thanks.